# IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries SQL0180 error

Tags: .net, db2, ibm-midrange, proc

I'm attempting to connect to IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries database via a .NET application and am receiving the following error when executing a DB2 stored procedure: "SQL0180 Syntax of date, time, or timestamp value not valid."

However, when i run the same stored procedure in the IBM Data Studio i get no error and it successfully returns a from the execution of the stored procedure. This leads me to believe it may be a driver issue and i'll need to update it.  Has anyone ran into this issue before and was it a driver update that fixed it?

Comment: put your query here

Answer (score 1):

I have faced similar issue in past.What you need to do is that in your connection string you need to specify the date format. We use *ISO so we add the below in our connection string

```
date format=iso
```

This should solve your date/timestamp issues.

Comment: I attempted to add that to my connection string and my connection failed.

Answer (score 0):

What version of OS400 is running on the host? I had date issues with V6R1. Updating to the latest Client Access PTF fixed them.

Answer (score 0):

The default path for the tool will include your username in it.  It then takes that username and looks for data inside a library of the same name.  If there are no libraries with the name being the username then it will fail. Two solutions: modify the default path to not include the username, or to add a library of the username.